# Could not load type 'Castle.Core.Internal.SlimReaderWriterLock'

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-windsor

I am using Castle 2.5.1 in my project where I reference a third-party assembly using NHibernate that seems to be using an incompatible version of NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle (2.1.0.4000).

Now I receive the following exception:

`The type initializer for 'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactory' threw an exception.`

with inner exception:

`Could not load type 'Castle.Core.Internal.SlimReaderWriterLock' from assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc'.`

From what I can gather is seems that `SlimReaderWriterLock` has been renamed.

I don't ever use NHibernate so any help solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/6ee90dedebbb5d18

Comment: @st_stefanov: Thanks, I came across this too but it doesn't say how to fix it.  I'll have a look at the AR download.  Sounds like it contains a newer version.  Will try to pull that out.

Comment: Yes, latest version should be your first step for now. Let us know.

Comment: Doesn't work :( --- it is trying to locate the related new version of NHibernate also.

Comment: Yes, all of them should be compitable. There are dependencies between them, as you know, so could you please try to get a full package of the DLL's which are compitable. Castle.Core.dll, NHibernate.dll, Castle.ActiveRecord.dll, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll

Comment: I tried with the latest version but then there are configuration issues.  I am going to try and use the old NHIbernate and build the NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle using my newer Castle reference.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Castle.Core version 3.2 using Nuget Packages. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded NH 2.1.0GA and extracted the ByteCode projects.

Then referenced the new Castle 2.5.1 assemblies and made the necessary namespace changes.